# Turpentine Cache policy for product list page for customer group

Tags: catalog, varnish, turpentine

i have Magento 1.9.1.0 and Varnish with the plugin Turpentine for caching.
I have different customer group. I defined a rule that some products are hidden for a specific customer group so each of them will view different "product list page"
My problem is that this page is cached so is always the same for each customer group. Is there a way to implement a esi cache policy for the product list page for customer group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We merged a [PR](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/pull/838) a while ago to solve this issue. It did't make it to master just yet, but you can try the new features from the devel branch.